# Apache: version krb5_3_MIT not defined in file libkrb5.so.3 with link time reference

Tags: linux, apache, kerberos, rhel7

The following steps create the issue:

1. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include apache's libraries:

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/apache-2.4/apache/lib:/lib64`
2. Start apache server
3. Make request (as a client) with kerberos authentication requiring to run kinit

   `kinit -kt /path/to/kerberos.kt principal@REALM.COM`
4. Error occurs due to:

   `kinit: relocation error: kinit: symbol krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_pac_request, version krb5_3_MIT not defined in file libkrb5.so.3 with link time reference`

Answer (score 0):

Apache lib includes kerberos libraries which should be included after /lib64.
Export /lib64 before apache's library directory.
[Refer to Solution](https://support.infoworks.io/support/solutions/articles/14000103864-how-to-resolve-error-like-kinit-relocation-error-kinit-symbol-krb5-get-init-creds-opt-set-pac-requ)

````
``` export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/path/to/apache-2.4/apache/lib ```
````